# Overlay more than two images using PIL python

Tags: python, merge, python-imaging-library

Hi i am using the below code to merge more than one image using PIL module

```
from PIL import Image

img0 = Image.open("w1.png")
img0 = img0.convert('RGBA')

img1 = Image.open("body.png")
img1 = img1.convert('RGBA')

img0.paste(img1, (0,0), img1)

img0.save('0.png')

img2 = Image.open("0.png")
img2 = img2.convert('RGBA')

img3 = Image.open("d1.png")
img3 = img3.convert('RGBA')

img2.paste(img3, (0,0), img3)

img2.show()
```

would like to know if there is way i can merge more than two images.
i have 8 images that i need to merge.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> would like to know if there is way i can merge more than two images. i have 8 images that i need to merge.

Just... keep `paste`-ing new images on?

All `Image.paste` does is merge the parameter image onto the subject, you can keep doing that, and it'll keep merging the new images.

Comment: yes i am pasting it but the code gets lengthy is there a way to short it?

Comment: @Zac Maybe just use a loop!?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to merge img，I suggesting a tool called `stegsolve`

There is a download url:
https://github.com/eugenekolo/sec-tools/tree/master/stego/stegsolve/stegsolve

There is usage:
[image]